# Foo < Bar in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I recently discovered that you can detect if a class/module includes another class/module. For example `Array` is `Enumerable` so you can do

```
Array < Enumerable # true
```

`String` however is not enumerable

```
String < Enumerable #nil
```

What exactly is happening here? How does this syntax work in ruby?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how to get the ancestor chain for a class:

```
>> Array.ancestors
=> [Array, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

The < method returns true if a class is "left" of another class in the ancestor chain and false otherwise:

```
>> Array < Object
=> true
>> Array < Enumerable
=> true
```

The < method returns false if a class is not "left" or another class in the ancestor chain.

```
>> Enumerable < Array
=> false
>> Array < Array
=> false
```

Enumerable is a module that is mixed in in to the Array class, but not mixed in to the String class.

```
>> Array.ancestors
=> [Array, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
>> String.ancestors
=> [String, Comparable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

If you include the Enumerable model into the String class, it returns true as well.

```
class String
  include Enumerable
end

# Enumerable is now included in String
String < Enumerable #true
```

The syntax works because of syntactic sugar.  Everything is an object in Ruby and syntactic sugar is even used in basic operations like addition:

```
>> 3 + 4
=> 7
>> 3.+(4)
=> 7
```

The explicit syntax for the < method is as follows:

```
>> Array.<(Object)
=> true
>> Array.send(:<, Object)
=> true
```

Answer (score 4):

> What exactly is happening here? How does this syntax work in ruby?

The `String` and `Array` classes inherit from the `Class` class which inherits from the `Module` class which [defines](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Module#%3C-instance_method) the `<` class method as:

> Returns true if the module is a subclass of the passed argument. Returns nil if there's no relationship between the two.

The syntax:

```
Array < Enumerable
String < Enumerable
```

can be seen as:

```
Array.< Enumerable
String.< Enumerable
```

Comment: The [`<=>` instance method](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Module#%3C%3D%3E-instance_method) of [`Class`](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Class) is irrelevant here. The [`<` instance method](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Module#%3C-instance_method) has its own definition that does not rely on `<=>`, as you can see by clicking “View source” in the docs.

Answer (score 3):

If the two modules appear in an ancestor chain, then the ordinary `<=>` applies with respect to their position in that chain. If not, `nil` is returned.